# What version of zlib is required for OpenVDB?

Tags: c++, dependencies, libraries, zlib, openvdb

The software I'm working on at work already uses zlib version 1.2.5-1, but I am getting ready to add some functionality that requires OpenVDB. In the INSTALL file in OpenVDB, it lists the required versions for all of its dependencies, except for zlib. Searching around on google and here has yielded no information about what version of zlib is required for OpenVDB to function properly.

Does anybody know from experience or superior Googling skills what the minimum version of zlib is for OpenVDB?

Comment: Go to zlib site or download the file, read the release notes they would have mentioned about changes and see does that changed has any impact with using openvdb. I just downloaded the zlib from net and using with openvdb. So far I haven't got any problem.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer That would require a pretty encyclopedic understanding of the innards of OpenVDB, zlib, and how OpenVDB uses zlib; something that I just don't have. There's a huge number of changes from 1.2.5.1 to 1.2.11 and I really have no idea for most of them if they change anything meaningful in this context or not.

Comment: @LethalProgrammer also, I'm sure that if you just downloaded the most up-to-date version of zlib from their website it would work with OpenVDB. That isn't, however, very helpful in determining if my out-of-date version will be compatible or not.

Comment: 1.2.8 version worked properly.